# When asked, "How much is enough?", did John D. Rockefeller say, "One more dollar"?

Tags: quotes

I've often seen this quoted with no link to a credible source. Here are just a few examples:

- https://starwinar.wordpress.com/daily-short-story/just-a-little-bit-more/
- http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/John_D._Rockefeller
- http://www.becomegoodsoil.com/how-much-is-enough/
- http://www.josephsangl.com/2006/04/24/how-much-is-enough/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The earliest reference Google Books has to the quote is in a book called ["Escaping the Time Crunch"](https://books.google.com/books?id=vk2sR7ul6dwC&q=%22one%20more%20dollar%22%20%22rockefeller%22&dq=%22one%20more%20dollar%22%20%22rockefeller%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB4N_nq7LNAhUG1GMKHR8CDzw4ChDoAQhGMAg), which was published in 1990.  So the first documented instance of this quote is very recent, and thus the quote is likely not based in historical fact.

Furthermore, the quote's premise contradicts many of Rockefeller's other well documented quotes on money such as [*"the impression was gaining ground with me that it was a good thing to let the money be my slave and not make myself a slave to money."*](https://books.google.com/books?id=tJDPAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA529&lpg=PA529&dq=%22let%20the%20money%20be%20my%20slave%20and%20not%20make%20myself%20a%20slave%20to%20money.%22&source=bl&ots=TJ7CAoWbav&sig=BY3qIj7c-aT7R5r7ZzqEssQJNy0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE16bfrLLNAhUM22MKHdkGCF8Q6AEIMTAF#v=onepage&q=%22let%20the%20money%20be%20my%20slave%20and%20not%20make%20myself%20a%20slave%20to%20money.%22&f=false)